# How to send list items to view part by part in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a product list and want to send them to view **part by part** in every page refresh, 5 per page. When all parts have been displayed start over at the beginning of the list on the next refresh. If the product list count is not dividend of 5, for example, count = 23, to come back to first. i.e. to take 15-20, then 20-2 (21, 22, 23, 1 and 2). Then, 3-8 and to continue.

I cannot use the paging rule as:

```
ViewBag.Result = db.Products.Skip( ( pageNo - 1 ) * 5).Take( 5 ).ToList();
```

Because, I will send that 5 products from all actions to views and update in every refreshing site.

I have an idea that to take random index and start, but I need to know the last sending index and in every refresh, send it to controller's current action. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the last sending index between the HTTP calls. Since ***HTTP is stateless***, you need a medium to keep it in between. You may use **Session** Variable do to that.

```
Session["LastIndexSent"]= 5;
return View(someITemList);
```

Also **try to avoid sending such Results in ViewBag**. Using dynamic stuff like `ViewBag/ViewData` to transfer data between controller and view makes your code ugly.Use strongly typed approach.

```
List<Product> productList=GetProductListFromSomeWhere();
return View(productList);
```

And in your strongly typed view,

```
@model List<Product>
@foreach(var prod in Model)
{
  <p>@prod.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: Yes i use ViewBag. I should write code to take elements part by part and will use your answer about session. then will say about result

Comment: I have not info about session. In this line:
 Session["LastIndexSent"]= 5;  is 5 default(start) value? How set default value to session variable? for start

Comment: Every time you sent some data to the View, Set the Session value, Next time, Read it and see what you sent last, Decide what to send next, do it . Update the session value